# Ruby case statement to Bash

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, command-line

How can this be translated to bash:

```
case ARGV[1]
  when 'English', 'en'
    dump_filename = "dump_english.sql"
  when 'French', 'fr'
    dump_filename = "dump_french.sql"
  else
    dump_filename = "dump.sql"
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the bash `case` statement:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg=$1

case "$arg" in
    English) file="dump_english.sql" ;;
         en) file="dump_english.sql" ;;
     French) file="dump_french.sql"  ;;
         fr) file="dump_french.sql"  ;;
          *) file="dump.sql"         ;;
esac

echo "$file"
```

Comment: You can combine several alternatives in a case statement, like this: `case "$arg" in en | English) ...;; fr | French) ...;; esac`.